# Batch operation on tensors in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-processing, tensor

I have a batches of images represented as TensorFlow tensor (say Tensor 1) of shape `(2,1024,1024,1)` of the form `(B,H,W,C)` where `B` is the batch size 2, `H` and `W` are image dimensions 1024 and `C` is the number of channels. Each element of this tensor (i.e. each pixel) stores a tuple `(a,b)` where both `a` and `b` are in the range `0` and `255`.

I have another tensor (say Tensor 2) of shape `(256,256)` for which each element stores a single value between `0` and `255`.

Given this setup, I have the following question.

I wish to replace each element value in Tensor 1 with the corresponding element value in Tensor 2. For example, let's assume that the element given by index `(1,200,500,1)` in tensor 1 contains the value `(100,20)`. I want to look up the value stored in Tensor 2 at pixel location `(100,200)` and modify the entry at `(1,200,500,1)` with this value.

How can I do this in the most efficient way possible for the entire batch?

Please let me know if something is unclear. I am a beginner to TensorFlow, hence would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

to replace an element value in Tensor 1 with a corresponding element value in Tensor 2 try this way

```
tensor1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((2,1024,1024,1)), trainable=False)
tensor2 = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,255, (255,255,1)), dtype='float32')

tensor12 = tensor1[1,200,500].assign(tensor2[100,200])
```

in this example, you substituted the element in position (1,200,500,1) of Tensor 1 with the element in position (100,200) of Tensor 2

---

```
batch_dim = 2
tensor1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((batch_dim,1024,1024,1)), trainable=False)
tensor2 = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,255, (1,255,255,1)), dtype='float32')

tensor12 = tensor1[:,:tensor2.shape[1],:tensor2.shape[2]].assign(tf.repeat(tensor2, batch_dim, axis=0))
```

with these lines, you assign all the value of tensor2 to the first (255,255) position in tensor1 for ALL the samples of the batch